# How to make bootable DVD for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

HI,

I have MAC OS X 10.6.4 dmg file. I want to make bootable DVD.

Do I have to convert it to ISO? Or just burning dmg file will do?

Any other things that needs to be done to make it bootable?

Please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Move this to superuser.com

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**If the `.DMG` file that you have is an image of an original Mac OS X 10.6.4 DVD, it will already be bootable. All you have to do is burn the image to a DVD, using Apple's Disk Utility** (found in the /Applications/Utilities folder on any Mac OS X installation).

If your `.DMG` file is illegally obtained, it may or may not include a proper boot sector, and in that case, you're on your own. Buy a legal copy of Mac OS X if you want to use it; it's more than reasonably priced.

A `.DMG` file is an Apple Disk Image, commonly found in the Mac world instead of the `.ISO` image file format common in Windows. You can easily convert between the two formats using Disk Utility or a host of other utilities. However, there should be no need to do this unless you are trying to burn the image from a Windows-based PC and your burning software of choice does not support burning from `.DMG` images, you may need to convert it to an ISO. [Nero Burning ROM](http://www.nero.com/enu/nero-burning-rom-overview.html) supports burning `.DMG` images, as does the free and most excellent [MagicISO](http://www.magiciso.com/download.htm). Alternatively, [dmg2iso](http://vu1tur.eu.org/tools/) can convert the image to an `.ISO` for burning in the software of your choice (of course, you more than likely will still not be able to read the contents of the image file in Windows because Mac OS X uses a different type of file system).